# how to do this in PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop

In Codeigniter, we can do :

`$this->select('users')->orderBy('id')->limit(20)`

I think this way of attaching methods to each other can work very good for me in my simple set of classes, but how to do it ?

Comment: Erhm, to localized? Please leave an explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called a fluent interface. To implement it, the function simply needs to return itself. Since the object is returned by reference, you can then chain together multiple calls:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function select($table)
    {
        // do stuff

        return $this;
    }

    public function orderBy($order)
    {
        // do stuff

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have this setup, would this: `$SomeClass->select($table)->orderBy($order)` be equal to `$SomeClass->select($table);$SomeClass->orderBy($order)`?

Comment: let me get this right. Now, i have to make a property in my class that holds the new statements added by every method ( orderBy, limit, .. ), ?, for example we would start by a SELECT query that would add `SELECT * FROM $table`, the next one adds `LIMIT $limit`, now i need a new method to actually execute the stored full statement as a query with mysql_query ?, am i getting this right ?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do really. I don't know how it works in Code Igniter but based on your example, your class represents the database query which you are building up programmatically. Once you've finished building up the query you either need a method to execute it (`$foo->select('users')->orderBy('id')->execute()`) or you pass the class to another object (`$query = $foo->select('users')->orderBy('id'); $db->query($query)`).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this by returning the object at the end of the function. For example:

```
class GreetClass {
    function __construct($greeting) {
        $this->greeting = $greeting;
    }
    function a() {
        echo $this->greeting;
        return $this;
    }
    function b() {
        echo ' ';
        return $this;
    }
    function c($who) {
        echo $who;
    }
}
$obj = new GreetClass('Hello');
$obj->a()->b()->c('World'); // Echoes: Hello World
```